# Existe crase em "à porta do carro"?

Tags: crase

Deve ser usada a crase na frase a seguir, considerando que este seria o título de um artigo?

> Aplicação de técnicas de vedação à porta do carro NinjaCar-X1.

Comment: A pergunta ficou algo vaga, porque em princípio *à porta* e *a porta* são ambas possíveis. Já tens uma resposta absolutamente correta, mas terias uma resposta mais diretamente dirigida às tuas dúvidas se explicasses por que razão hesitas entre *à porta* e *a porta*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, há provavelmente crase (escrevendo-se portanto *à*, tal como no título da pergunta). *Aplicação*, tal como o verbo *aplicar*, introduz o destinatário da aplicação com a preposição "a". Assim, quando muito, não havendo crase, seria por omissão do artigo definido "a". Contudo, essa possibilidade parece-me mais difícil de admitir:

> Aplicação de técnicas de vedação *a* porta do carro NinjaCar-X1

Não sendo completamente de excluir, no sentido genérico que eu creio que a frase tem (isto é, não estamos a falar de um veículo em particular), é praticamente obrigatório o artigo definido.

A exclusão do artigo seria mais natural em:

> Aplicação de técnicas de vedação *a* porta *de* carro NinjaCar-X1

Esta frase podia ser, por exemplo, o título de um relatório, em que se tentou aplicar dadas técnicas a uma viatura. Não tem o mesmo sentido genérico daquela que dás.

Comment: Tens andado de férias?

Comment: Sem artigo, mais natural ainda seria *a portas*.

Comment: @Jacinto O contrário, ando a trabalhar :)

Answer (score 1):

**UMA RESPOSTA SUCINTA**

Pode ou não existir crase em "a porta do carro", tudo depende do contexto:

- "a porta do carro está amassada" (não há crase, apenas o artigo definido);
- "ele estava de pé, junto à porta do carro" (há crase, preposição + artigo);
- "técnicas de vedação a portas" (não há crase, apenas a preposição);
- "técnicas de vedação à porta do carro" (há crase, é uma porta específica e requer o artigo);
- "Tua mão ficou cheirando a gasolina" (não há crase, apenas preposição sem artigo);
- "Tua mão ficou cheirando à gasolina que derramaste" (a preposição segue o verbo e a gasolina é especificada com o artigo, portanto há crase).

Answer (score 0):

Se o verbo principal puxar a preposição **a** e for seguido por um **substantivo feminino**, então usa-se crase.

Nesse caso, o verbo principal é **aplicar** e a palavra referente a **onde** se aplicará é **porta**, *porta* é subst. feminino, portanto usa-se sim a crase.

Veja que a crase só será usada antes da palavra referente a **onde** o verbo agirá se vier imediatamente antes de um *substantivo feminino*.

Exemplo: Apliquei a tinta **à tela**.

*tinta* = **o quê** irei *aplicar*

*tela* = substantivo feminino para **onde** irei *aplicar*

ps: no exemplo dado por Artefacto, ambas as frases usam crase, pois o verbo é "aplicar" e **onde** continua sendo **porta**, não *carro*. Independente se o carro for genérico ou não, como **porta** é substantivo feminino, usa-se crase.

Isso não aconteceria se a frase fosse, por exemplo:

Aplicar tinta **ao** carro.

No qual **onde** é o **carro** e *carro* é um **substantivo masculino**

Comment: Não estás a ver bem as coisas. A crase é uma fusão de duas vogais idênticas [(vê dicionário Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/crase); neste caso, da preposição ***a*** com o artigo ***a***; também pode ser com o artigo ***as***, que dá ***às***. Mas podemos usar o substantivo sem artigo: *cheiras a rosas; a cravos* (ou com artigo, *cheiras às rosas/aos cravos que eu te dei*). Do mesmo modo se usares *porta* sem artigo, fica *aplicação de vedante a porta* . Com a preposição ***em*** fica mais claro: com artigo, *aplicação na porta*; sem artigo, *aplicação em porta*.